# Sencha 2.0 App file size issue -

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have developed a small Sencha Touch 2.0 app. Here is the url:

http://apps.swarnendude.com/sencha/iphonetest/iphoneTest.html?url=http://apps.innofied.com/sencha/gts

The app works in perfectly fine in Android 2.3, iPad, iPhone, Blackberry Playbook. But the app crashes while I test in ***Blackberry Torch (OS: 6.0)*** giving this error:

"**The page you requested could not be loaded. It is too large for this device**"

The production version of the file sizes are:

sencha-touch.js: 90.5Kb

app-all.js: 401.4Kb

app-all.css: 151.5Kb

Other resources: 10Kb

So, total around 650Kb. I think the sizes can be reduced more but I am not getting any other options. I am using the least css configs in SASS file and in JS too (only which are required). Is there anyone getting the same problem? Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you attempted to minimize your app, so in this case, there's not much you could do.

I'm using Blackberry Bold and occasionally see this when I use native browser. But in some cases, **Opera Mini** and **Bolt Browser** are good suggestions to pass those errors.